# GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column issue solve without disabling full groupby variable from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing some groupby aggregation issue in my below join query:

```
SELECT chat_tbl.chatrec_id,
       chat_tbl.senderid,
       chat_tbl.receiverid,
       chat_tbl.msg,
       chat_tbl.chat_time,
       chat_tbl.chatuser_strid, 
       chatuser_link_tbl.str_id, 
       chatuser_link_tbl.modifytime 
FROM chat_tbl 
INNER JOIN chatuser_link_tbl ON chat_tbl.chatuser_strid = chatuser_link_tbl.str_id 
                            AND (chat_tbl.senderid=393 OR chat_tbl.receiverid=393) 
GROUP by chat_tbl.chatuser_strid 
ORDER by chatuser_link_tbl.modifytime DESC
```

I know I can disable the `only_full_group_by` setting by executing the following:

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

But that is the wrong method it will waive off the settings and this is again removed after every server restart so i want to correct my query. Please anyone can help me to correctly write this join query from 3 tables.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**: I am using this query to list all the chat done by the current user with other users.

I have 2 tables to do that chatuser_link_tbl has the link of the chat done between 2 users for example 11-18, 12-22 i.e concatenated 2 user id with dash - and chat table has an actual chat data.

I am using group by to group all the chats using chatuser_strid to get only single last record. I am displaying only last chat message with date time.

In short this is the same as whatsapp chat list (the first home screen) or like facebook messenger chat list. Which display user details with their last chat message.

Comment: You can only have values in your `SELECT` list that is either an aggregate function (like `MAX()`, `SUM()`, `COUNT()` etc) and the fields that are present in your`GROUP BY`, when using grouped queries.

Comment: Why are you even using a `GROUP BY` clause here?

Comment: @Qirel Would you please re write that query with your suggestions to make it correct?

Comment: I suggest that you take a SQL tutorial and understand what everything does. Do you understand what `GROUP BY` does? Because I fail to see why you have used it here. And I'll bet that if you take it out, you'll make some progress..

Comment: You should explain the query meaning first. What are you trying to achieve exactly, and which are the fields of both tables that you need to be retrieved for your application

Comment: Qirel I know what groupBy does and that is why i wrote query. also i know about sql. You can review my updated question. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasG I have added more details to my question please have a look.

Comment: Which column represents last record? And please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: @RiyaParmar If you know what `GROUP BY` does, then why have you used it like that, and without any aggregate functions? Using `GROUP BY` alone to get the last record doesn't work, but you can fetch the latest records with an aggregate function in combination with it.

Comment: *I am using group by to group all the chats using chatuser_strid to get only single last record. i am displaying only last chat message with date time.* GROUP BY cannot solve this task - it may get only random row from a group. You must add a subquery which uses another copy of `chat_tbl` and selects maximal `chat_time` per  `chatuser_strid` (or maybe `chatuser_link_tbl` and maximal `modifytime`?), then join this subquery and use its values in WHERE condition.

Comment: @ Akina ok i'll try that way..

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue myself. Below query worked for me to get desired result.

**ANY_VALUE** helped me.

```
SELECT chat_tbl.chatuser_strid, ANY_VALUE(chat_tbl.chatrec_id),ANY_VALUE(chat_tbl.senderid),ANY_VALUE(chat_tbl.receiverid),ANY_VALUE(chat_tbl.msg),ANY_VALUE(chat_tbl.chat_time), ANY_VALUE(chatuser_link_tbl.str_id)       
FROM chat_tbl      
INNER JOIN chatuser_link_tbl      
ON chat_tbl.chatuser_strid = chatuser_link_tbl.str_id AND (chat_tbl.senderid=".$userid." OR chat_tbl.receiverid=".$userid.")       
GROUP by chat_tbl.chatuser_strid      
ORDER by ANY_VALUE(chatuser_link_tbl.modifytime) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is designed to work on a single user (sender or receiver equal to 393) you can simply drop the group by and add a limit

```
SELECT chat_tbl.chatrec_id,
       chat_tbl.senderid,
       chat_tbl.receiverid,
       chat_tbl.msg,
       chat_tbl.chat_time,
       chat_tbl.chatuser_strid, 
       chatuser_link_tbl.str_id, 
       chatuser_link_tbl.modifytime 
FROM chat_tbl 
INNER JOIN chatuser_link_tbl ON chat_tbl.chatuser_strid = chatuser_link_tbl.str_id 
                            AND (chat_tbl.senderid=393 OR chat_tbl.receiverid=393) 
ORDER by chatuser_link_tbl.modifytime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If you were doing this just to test, and you want your final query to operate on all users. You can use window functions (LAST_VALUE) or a lateral join if your version of MySQL supports any of these. If that is the case, I can expand on my answer.

Comment: This query will give only single records, I want all the chat table's record which are having either receiver id = 393 or sender id = 393. For example you might have done the chat with multiple user's not only single user. For example check you facebook messanger where it shows list of all the users and their last message with whom you have chatted with.hope it's clear now.

Comment: In that case Gordon't answer should be exactly what you need. The only problem might arise from the chatuser_strid that would show twice for pairs (f ex 11-22 and 22-11)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use window functions for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT c.*, cl.str_id, cl.modifytime,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.chat_user_strid ORDER BY cul.modifytime DESC)
      FROM chat_tbl c JOIN
           chatuser_link_tbl cul
           ON c.chatuser_strid = cul.str_id AND
              393 IN (c.senderid, c.receiverid) 
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```